# Dynamic Form in Aurelia

Tags: aurelia

I am currently building a dynamic form with Aurelia, i.e. a form that is defined as a JSON object. This structure definition will also contain loose binding expressions that should be resolved at runtime. A very simplified example would look like this:

```
[
  {
    "type": "text",
    "text": "Welcome {person:details.firstName} {person:details.lastName}!"
  },
  {
    "type": "checkbox",
    "checked": false,
    "bindings": {
      "checked": "person:isInterested"
    }
  }
]
```

So binding expressions could be "inline" (in case the respective property is a string and only a one-way-binding is needed. In case the property is not a string or a two-way-binding is required it would be defined via a bindings-object.

Rendering the form itself is not an issue (I've done this via [dynamic UI composition](http://aurelia.io/hub.html#/doc/article/aurelia/templating/latest/templating-dynamic-ui-composition)). Also I have written a data-provider which interface looks like this

```
registerSource(prefix, object)
getValue(expression) -> object
setValue(expression, value)
parseString(string) -> string
```

This allows the registrations of objects that should be used as sources (like the person object used in the example above). Also it could get and set values based on the expression language shown in the example, e.g. getValue('person:details.firstName') would resolve the expression if a source with the name "person" is registered and returns the string "John". parseString('Hello {person:details.firstName}!') would return the string "Hello John!".

The data provider is required since it also has to handle cascading, i.e. getValue('person:greeting') -> "Dear John Doe" if person:greeting resolves to "Dear ${person:first} ${person:last}".

I currently struggle with the implementation.

A easy approach would be just add the data-provider in the view model of the element, like

```
…
get checked() {
  let expression = …; // get expression from the json definition
  return this._dataProvider.getValue(expression);
}

set checked(checked) {
  let expression = …; // get expression from the json definition
  this._dataProvider.setValue(expression, checked);
}
…
```

This works, but the view does not get notified (i.e. refreshes) if the data source is refreshed. Of course it would be possible to trigger a event that refreshes the view, but this feels definitely like a work around.

Does anybody has a better idea how to solve this problem? Would binding behaviors be a solutions? I would really appreciate any help or hint here.

Thanks!

Comment: It wouldn't hurt to check out my blog post where I go over some code that does something along the lines of what you want to do. You can check it out here: https://aurelia.ninja/2017/07/09/getting-my-hands-dirty-with-aurelias-binding-engine/

Comment: Thank for your really great blog post, it did indeed help me a lot! :)